# Can you use appSettings keys in other parts of web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, appsettings

Somewhere in my ASP.NET web.config is this bit of configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In my appSettings, I have this key:

```
<add key="customErrors" value="on" />
```

My question: can I set the `system.web/customErrors` node with the value of the `customErrors` appSettings key?

Comment: not out of the box but you will have to write your own code where you will read the settings from appsettings and then update the value of customerrors key.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to handle it programmatically - `<system.web>` is an accessible section of `web.config`

Since IIS will restart the Application Pool associated with your web application every time you edit `web.config`, you can handle this in `Application_Start` in `Global.asax`

You'll need a mechanism to avoid going into an infinite restart loop here, like checking if the values are equal, and only updating `web.config` if they're not.